Can PowerShell compare files and list those are the same size?
I have thousands of photos and movies that I’m trying to clean up.
Many of the files are duplicates but have a different name.
I want to loop through a folder and if two or more files have the same size, show the file names as an output so I can go back and review each to see if they are a duplicate or not.
Running this I can sort by file size, but it is a full list of files.
Is there a way I can only output the same sized files?
get-childitem $path -recurse -filter "*.mov" |
  group-object length |
  sort-object name -desc


Pipe your output to Where-Object -Property Count -GT -Value 1 and you have only the ones with doublettes

I recommend against using identical file-sizes as a way to check for duplicates, because many files will have the same size by sheer coincidence, but also because plenty of software that writes/edits images on-disk might write empty/zero-valued bytes after the end of the file if they're careless with how they're using a buffer in C, for example), so you might end-up with different photos all being sized some multiple of 4096 bytes. Instead, I recommend you read their hashes instead.

Meaning, if the question is actually Can PowerShell compare files and list those are the same? -s-i-z-e-?-, it is a dupplicate with: how to speed up ForEach-Object MD5/hash check.

You can filter where the groups have more than 1 item using Where-Object as Olaf pointed out in his comment. Something to consider, filtering by .Length isn't enough to determine if 2 or more files are the same, you should use Get-FileHash to ensure that.
Here is how you could approach your code:
Get-ChildItem $path -Recurse -Filter '*.mov' |
    Group-Object Length |
    # where there are 2 or more files
    Where-Object Count -GT 1 |
    # get the MD5 to be sure they're the same
    ForEach-Object { $_.Group | Get-FileHash -Algorithm MD5 } |
    Group-Object Hash |
    # if 2 or more files have the same hash you can safely remove them
    Where-Object Count -GT 1 |
    # skip 1 item and remove the rest
    ForEach-Object { $_.Group | Select-Object -Skip 1 } |
    # Remove `-WhatIf` after confirming its doing what's expected
    Remove-Item -WhatIf

